# Checking Value in multiple column for a given Group

Tags: sql, sql-server

i am not sure how to get this in SQL 2008

For a same postal code there are multiple client and having RelationNo
and i am trying to find missing Relation number
when a same postal code has two or more client number and any one phone number of those client is same
then same trade number will be updated where it is missing or NULL or Blank

IF PHONE NUMBER IS NOT PRESENT NO ACTION.

may someone please suggest how to do in sql

Table:

```
DECLARE @MASTER TABLE
(
POSTAL VARCHAR (50),
CLIENT VARCHAR (50),
phone1 INT,
phone2 INT,
RelationNo VARCHAR (50)
)

INSERT @MASTER




SELECT 'M169HE',    'E5017766',016187,88888,'E100' UNION ALL
SELECT 'M169HE',    'M0111136', '', 016187, '' UNION ALL
SELECT 'IV11UF',    'E3009949', 50505,  '', 'F200' UNION ALL
SELECT 'KA48HH',    'E3087713', 01290,  '', '' UNION ALL
SELECT 'KA48HH',    'E3017126', 55665,  01290,  'G999' UNION ALL
SELECT 'KA48HH',    'E5005326', '', 55665,  '' UNION ALL
SELECT 'YO72LZ',    'C5640095', '', '', 'T8888' UNION ALL
SELECT 'YO72LZ',    'C5640096', '', '', ''
```

Output:

```
POSTAL| CLIENT  |phone1  |  phone2| RelationNo
M169HE| E5017766|16187   |88888   |E100
M169HE| M0111136|        |16187   |E100
IV11UF| E3009949|   50505|        |F200
KA48HH| E3087713|   1290 |        |G999
KA48HH| E3017126|   55665|1290    |G999
KA48HH| E5005326|        |55665   |G999
YO72LZ| C5640095|        |  T8888 |
YO72LZ| C5640096|        |        |
```

Thanks

Comment: can you show the expected output as well?

Comment: @vkp: i have shown under Output.

Comment: What if  `SELECT 'KA48HH',    'E8888888', 01290,  '', 'G888' UNION ALL` ...  is added ?

Comment: @Serg: In such Case any one Relation Number is good enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [**`cross apply`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx) inside a [**`common table expression`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) to find and update the matching `RelationNo` for those rows missing `RelationNo`:

test setup: http://rextester.com/YARZ79913

```
;with cte as (
  select o.*, x.FoundRelationNo
    from @MASTER as o
    cross apply (
      select top 1 FoundRelationNo = i.RelationNo 
        from @MASTER  as i
        where i.Postal = o.Postal
          and nullif(i.relationno,'') is not null
          and (
             nullif(i.phone1,0) in (o.phone1, o.phone2)
          or nullif(i.phone2,0) in (o.phone1, o.phone2)
              )
        ) as x
    where nullif(o.relationno,'') is null
     and (o.phone1 > 0 or o.phone2 > 0)
 )
 --select * from cte
 update cte set RelationNo = FoundRelationNo

 select * from @MASTER
```

results:

```
+--------+----------+--------+--------+------------+
| POSTAL |  CLIENT  | phone1 | phone2 | RelationNo |
+--------+----------+--------+--------+------------+
| M169HE | E5017766 |  16187 |  88888 | E100       |
| M169HE | M0111136 |      0 |  16187 | E100       |
| IV11UF | E3009949 |  50505 |      0 | F200       |
| KA48HH | E3087713 |   1290 |      0 | G999       |
| KA48HH | E3017126 |  55665 |   1290 | G999       |
| KA48HH | E5005326 |      0 |  55665 | G999       |
| YO72LZ | C5640095 |      0 |      0 | T8888      |
| YO72LZ | C5640096 |      0 |      0 |            |
+--------+----------+--------+--------+------------+
```

Comment: Really no need for cte. `update o set RelationNo = FoundRelationNo from  @MASTER as o ...`

Comment: Agreed, this is overkill.

Comment: @iamdave sure, since you edited the question and removed the line that said "trade number will be updated where it is missing".

Comment: @Serg I used the cte so that when OP applies this to his specific use case they can easily switch between reviewing the changes that would be made by using `select * from cte` and applying those changes with `update cte ...` The original questions specifically requests "trade number will be updated where it is missing".

Comment: @SqlZim One can achive easy toggling SELECT / UPDATE just with comments.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a simple `apply` and `union all`:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(POSTAL VARCHAR (50),
                        CLIENT VARCHAR (50),
                        phone1 INT,
                        phone2 INT,
                        RelationNo VARCHAR (50)
                        )

INSERT @t
SELECT 'M169HE',    'E5017766',016187,88888,'E100' UNION ALL
SELECT 'M169HE',    'M0111136', '', 016187, '' UNION ALL
SELECT 'IV11UF',    'E3009949', 50505,  '', 'F200' UNION ALL
SELECT 'KA48HH',    'E3087713', 01290,  '', '' UNION ALL
SELECT 'KA48HH', 'E8888888', 01290, '', 'G888' UNION ALL
SELECT 'KA48HH',    'E3017126', 55665,  01290,  'G999' UNION ALL
SELECT 'KA48HH',    'E5005326', '', 55665,  '' UNION ALL
SELECT 'YO72LZ',    'C5640095', '', '', 'T8888' UNION ALL
SELECT 'YO72LZ',    'C5640096', '', '', '' 

select t.POSTAL
        ,t.CLIENT
        ,t.phone1
        ,t.phone2
        ,tt.RelationNo
from @t t
    outer apply(select top 1 RelationNo
                from @t t2
                where t.POSTAL = t2.POSTAL
                    and t.CLIENT <> t2.CLIENT
                    and (nullif(t.phone1,0) in(t2.phone1,t2.phone2)
                        or nullif(t.phone2,0) in(t2.phone1,t2.phone2)
                        )
                    and t2.RelationNo <> ''
                ) tt
where t.RelationNo = ''

union all

select *
from @t
where RelationNo <> ''
order by 1;
```

Output:

```
+--------+----------+--------+--------+------------+
| POSTAL |  CLIENT  | phone1 | phone2 | RelationNo |
+--------+----------+--------+--------+------------+
| IV11UF | E3009949 |  50505 |      0 | F200       |
| KA48HH | E8888888 |   1290 |      0 | G888       |
| KA48HH | E3017126 |  55665 |   1290 | G999       |
| KA48HH | E3087713 |   1290 |      0 | G888       |
| KA48HH | E5005326 |      0 |  55665 | G999       |
| M169HE | M0111136 |      0 |  16187 | E100       |
| M169HE | E5017766 |  16187 |  88888 | E100       |
| YO72LZ | C5640096 |      0 |      0 | NULL       |
| YO72LZ | C5640095 |      0 |      0 | T8888      |
+--------+----------+--------+--------+------------+
```